# Replacing light switch with dimmer switch... white wire?

Tags: electrical, wiring, switch, dimmer-switch

On a three gang switch, I'm replacing a single pole light switch with an electronic dimmer and a second single pole light switch with a WeMo switch.  The third switch is getting replaced with a similar switch.  The current configuration into each "old" switch is black, black(red) & ground.  There are 4 white wires from the wall not attached to any of the three switches but grouped together.  Both the dimmer and the WeMo switch ask for a neutral white wire.  My question is "can I group all white wires together (from dimmer and from WeMo with the 4 white wires from wall) or do I need to identify the white wire specific to the WeMo switch and the white wire specific to the dimmer switch instead?" In other words, instead of 6 white wires together (WeMo, dimmer and 4 from wall), would it be 3 separate white wire connections (WeMo white with white from wall, dimmer white with white from wall, and the rest of the whites grouped together).  All three light switches are on the same circuit, by the way.

Comment: Are the lights all on the same circuit?

Answer (score 1):

Since the 4 white wires are already connected, they need to stay connected.  It would be correct to wire all 6 whites together.  Note that for 6x #14 wires you need to use a new red wire nut.

Comment: Thanks.  All 6 white wires connected worked ok.  I ended up using the next larger size of wire nut (grey) to ensure all cables were secured.